# Truncate a string, 'nicely', to a number of *bytes*

Tags: elixir

Say I have a string, like `s = "abcdé"`, that I want to truncate to a number of *bytes*, in this example five (5). But, because the last 'grapheme' consists of multiple bytes, I'd like `byte_truncate_nicely(s, 5) == "abcd"` to be true, as it doesn't seem sensible to, e.g. use `binary_part`, and split the final grapheme.

Comment: How `"á̀̃é̀̃"` is supposed to be splitted? It’s 8 bytes fwiw.

Comment: Oddly enough, Elixir reports 14 bytes. I wonder if that's something with the copy pasting.

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer Ah, indeed, 14. Each diacritical symbol is 2 bytes and there are 3 per vowel.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Good test case! `byte_truncate_nicely("á̀̃é̀̃", 5) == ""` should be true as `byte_size("á̀̃")` is apparently `7`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if the function like this exists, but you can write it yourself

```
bytes_number = 5

"abcdé"
|> String.split("") 
|> Enum.reduce_while("", 
   fn char, acc -> 
     if byte_size(acc <> char) <= bytes_number do
       {:cont, acc <> char}
     else
       {:halt, acc}
     end
   end)
```

Comment: You use reduce_while, which is stricly speaking faster than my implementation. I still traverse the entire string.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no built-in way to do this, but you sure can do it by hand.

```
  def take_bytes(str, limit) do
    str
    |> String.graphemes()
    |> Enum.reduce({[], 0}, fn g, {acc, sum} ->
      next_size = byte_size(g)

      if sum + next_size > limit do
        {acc, sum}
      else
        {[g | acc], sum + next_size}
      end
    end)
    |> elem(0)
    |> Enum.join()
  end
```

If you turn the string into graphemes, you can measure how many bytes they take up. Then it's just a matter of "eating" as many graphemes as you want.

Example:

```
iex(1)> byte_size("á̀̃é̀̃")       
14
iex(2)> T.take_bytes("á̀̃é̀̃", 6)        
""
iex(3)> T.take_bytes("á̀̃é̀̃", 7)
"á̀̃"
iex(4)> T.take_bytes("á̀̃é̀̃", 14)
"é̀̃á̀̃"
iex(5)> T.take_bytes("á̀̃é̀̃", 13)
"á̀̃"
```

Comment: This is probably not the expected result: `T.take_bytes("foo" <> <<0x308 :: utf8>> <> "x", 4)` → `"xof"` (U+0308 is a combining diaeresis)

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity:

```rb
for <<c :: utf8 <- "abcdé">>, reduce: "" do
  acc when byte_size(acc <> <<c :: utf8>>) <= 5 ->
     acc <> <<c :: utf8>>
  acc ->
     acc
end
#⇒ "abcd"
```

Or, even fancier (but less correct):

```rb
for <<c <- "abcdé">>,
  reduce: "",
  do: (acc when c < 128 -> acc <> <<c>>; acc -> acc)
#⇒ "abcd"

for <<c <- "abcde">>,
  reduce: "",
  do: (acc when c < 128 -> acc <> <<c>>; acc -> acc)
#⇒ "abcde"
```

*NB* this one does not produce the correct result, as well as two other answers posted here; mostly because there is no correct answer for the problem stated.

Comment: I guess reduce_while is necessary there, try "aéc" for all you cases

Comment: @apelsinka223 no, I just missed `:: utf8` qualifier in the first snippet in the very first assignment (updated.) The latter surely won’t work with diacritics, no matter what, because of strict ASCII guard.

Comment: What do you mean that "there is no correct answer for the problem stated"?